# Get List Names of all Lists using particular site columns

Tags: list, powershell, guid

I need to get the names of all the lists using specific site columns. I've got the following code

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://nameofsite/sites/subsite"
$filePath = "E:\lists.txt"
$array = "array of site column names"

foreach ($element in $array)
{
  $column = $web.Fields[$element]
  $column.ListsFieldUsedIn() | Out- File -FilePath $filePath -Append

}
```

ListsFieldUsedIn() is returning the web id and list id in each web id. Is there any way to get the list of names based on the list id that is returned? This would make it easier to identify the lists. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://nameofsite/sites/subsite"
$filePath = "E:\lists.txt"
$array = "array of site column names"    
 $column = $site.RootWeb.AvailableFields[$element]
 $lists = $column.ListsFieldUsedIn()
 $column.ListsFieldUsedIn() | ForEach-Object {
  $w = $site.AllWebs[$_.WebID]
  $l = $w.Lists[$_.ListID]
 "Web:" +$w.Title+ "  List: " + $l.Title+ " ListUrl: " +$l.RootFolder.Url |      Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append 

 }
```

Based on code I found here [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18809/is-it-possible-to-iterate-all-lists-in-sharepoint-in-search-for-a-given-field)