# SharePoint lookup field in workflows

Tags: workflow-activity

I am using a 2013 workflow to delete an item. If that item is part of a lookup field of some other item, it cannot be deleted. The workflow will stop with an error. How do I know if an item is part of a lookup field in some other item before it can be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once posted a similar(ish) question to yours, I needed to find all look-up fields that 'point' to a list.

In my [answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227830/find-all-lookup-fields-that-point-to-a-list/232191#232191) I included a link to powershell, which Mike Smith (a respected SPSE contributor) posted on his own website.  I didn't use the powershell, I don't know how to, but perhaps you can and hence would get a better way of resolving your questions than I did!